# how to schedule a macro automatically in outlook?

Tags: powershell, vbscript, macros, outlook

i want to know how to schedule automatically a macro for outlook.
I 've created one macro which extract the attached file from an email and store it in a folder.
This macro is working very well when i execute it by clicking macro "execute".

But i want this macro execute automatically everyday for example at 08:30 before coming to my office.

Thank you

Comment: Please someone can help me. i'm new in outlook macro. i tried to create a script file with powershell and then execute it , it's not working. Even from a batch file. thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use:

1. A [vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs) to automate Outlook. I've added sample `vbscript` for saving an attachment from the first item in the Outlook inbox below. The main differences between the `vbscript` and the equivalent `vba` automated from an app such as Excel is that in vbscript you can't declare types explicitly (ie VBA's `Dim strTest As String` is `Dim StrTest` in `vbscript`
2. Use Windows task scheduler to schedule daily execution.
3. You will probably need [Click Yes](http://www.contextmagic.com/express-clickyes/free-version.htm) to suppress the Outlook security messages.

   ```
   Dim objApp
   Dim olNs
   Dim olInbox
   Dim olMsg
   Dim olAtt
   On Error Resume Next
   Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
   Set olNs = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   Set olInbox = olNs.getdefaultfolder(6)
   Set olMsg = olInbox.items(1)
   If olMsg.attachments.Count > 0 Then
       Set olAtt = olMsg.attachments(1)
       olAtt.SaveAsFile "c:\temp\" & olAtt.Filename
   End If
   objApp.Quit
   Set objApp = Nothing
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes i try to put the vbs file in windows task, i use win7 and i have the following error message:

Comment: when i launch the this vbs file, it says error on every SET, End If, objapp